# How to easily see the syntax of functions in R?

Tags: r, syntax

I am struggling to learn R since I cannot find a good way to see the syntax of the functions.

For example: I am practicing the rename function, I have a video guiding it, but it's not Ideal. When I've learned python it had the shift + Tab option that showed exactly what is mandatory, the order, etc. It was not perfect, but I know I can get away with it 80% of the times.

There's a good way to guide yourself in R, like the Shift + tab in Python?

Comment: Simply try ?function or ??function.

Comment: Tab-completion after typing `yourfunctionname(` should work to show all the arguments to the function. Otherwise `args(yourfunctionname)`

Comment: If you type the function name without `()`, it will show you the full source of the function.  The first part tells you what the arguments are, the rest tells you what it does.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.